# Discerning lifetimes understanding the move keyword

Tags: rust

I've been playing around with AudioUnit via Rust and the Rust library [coreaudio-rs](https://github.com/RustAudio/coreaudio-rs). Their example seems to work well:

```
extern crate coreaudio;

use coreaudio::audio_unit::{AudioUnit, IOType};
use coreaudio::audio_unit::render_callback::{self, data};
use std::f32::consts::PI;


struct Iter {
    value: f32,
}
impl Iterator for Iter {
    type Item = [f32; 2];
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<[f32; 2]> {
        self.value += 440.0 / 44_100.0;
        let amp = (self.value * PI * 2.0).sin() as f32 * 0.15;
        Some([amp, amp])
    }
}


fn main() {
    run().unwrap()
}

fn run() -> Result<(), coreaudio::Error> {
    // 440hz sine wave generator.

    let mut samples = Iter { value: 0.0 };
    //let buf: Vec<[f32; 2]> = vec![[0.0, 0.0]];
    //let mut samples = buf.iter();

    // Construct an Output audio unit that delivers audio to the default output device.
    let mut audio_unit = try!(AudioUnit::new(IOType::DefaultOutput));

    // Q: What is this type?
    let callback = move |args| {
        let Args { num_frames, mut data, .. } = args;
        for i in 0..num_frames {
            let sample = samples.next().unwrap();
            for (channel_idx, channel) in data.channels_mut().enumerate() {
                channel[i] = sample[channel_idx];
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    };

    type Args = render_callback::Args<data::NonInterleaved<f32>>;
    try!(audio_unit.set_render_callback(callback));
    try!(audio_unit.start());

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(30000));

    Ok(())
}
```

However, changing it up a little bit to load via a buffer doesn't work as well:

```
extern crate coreaudio;

use coreaudio::audio_unit::{AudioUnit, IOType};
use coreaudio::audio_unit::render_callback::{self, data};

fn main() {
    run().unwrap()
}

fn run() -> Result<(), coreaudio::Error> {
    let buf: Vec<[f32; 2]> = vec![[0.0, 0.0]];
    let mut samples = buf.iter();

    // Construct an Output audio unit that delivers audio to the default output device.
    let mut audio_unit = try!(AudioUnit::new(IOType::DefaultOutput));

    // Q: What is this type?
    let callback = move |args| {
        let Args { num_frames, mut data, .. } = args;
        for i in 0..num_frames {
            let sample = samples.next().unwrap();
            for (channel_idx, channel) in data.channels_mut().enumerate() {
                channel[i] = sample[channel_idx];
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    };

    type Args = render_callback::Args<data::NonInterleaved<f32>>;
    try!(audio_unit.set_render_callback(callback));
    try!(audio_unit.start());

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(30000));

    Ok(())
}
```

It says, correctly so, that `buf` only lives until the end of `run` and does not live long enough for the audio unit—which makes sense, because "borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...".
In any case, that doesn't bother me; I can modify the iterator to load and read from the buffer just fine. However, it does raise some questions:

1. Why does the `Iter { value: 0.0 }` have the `'static` lifetime?
2. If it doesn't have the `'static` lifetime, why does it say the borrowed value must be valid for the `'static` lifetime?
3. If it does have the `'static` lifetime, why? It seems like it would be on the heap and closed on by `callback`.
4. I understand that the `move` keyword allows moving inside the closure, which doesn't help me understand why it interacts with lifetimes. Why can't it move the buffer? Do I have to move both the buffer and the iterator into the closure? How would I do that?
5. Over all this, **how do I figure out the expected lifetime without trying to be a compiler myself**? It doesn't seem like guessing and compiling is always a straightforward method to resolving these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the `Iter { value: 0.0 }` have the `'static` lifetime?

It doesn't; only references have lifetimes.

> why does it say the borrowed value must be valid for the `'static` lifetime
>
> how do I figure out the expected lifetime without trying to be a compiler myself

Read the documentation; it tells you the restriction:

```
fn set_render_callback<F, D>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<(), Error> 
where
    F: FnMut(Args<D>) -> Result<(), ()> + 'static, // <====
    D: Data
```

This restriction means that any references inside of `F` must live at least as long as the  `'static` lifetime. Having no references is also acceptable.

All type and lifetime restrictions are expressed at the function boundary — this is a hard rule of Rust.

> I understand that the `move` keyword allows moving inside the closure, which doesn't help me understand why it interacts with lifetimes.

The only thing that the `move` keyword does is force every variable *directly used* in the closure to be moved into the closure. Otherwise, the compiler tries to be conservative and move in references/mutable references/values based on the usage inside the closure.

> Why can't it move the buffer?

The variable `buf` is never used inside the closure.

> Do I have to move both the buffer and the iterator into the closure? How would I do that?

By creating the iterator inside the closure. Now `buf` is used inside the closure and will be moved:

```
let callback = move |args| {
    let mut samples = buf.iter();
    // ...
}
```

> It doesn't seem like guessing and compiling is always a straightforward method to resolving these issues.

Sometimes it is, and sometimes you have to think about why you believe the code to be correct and why the compiler states it isn't and come to an understanding.

Comment: "Sometimes it is, and sometimes you have to think about why you believe the code to be correct and why the compiler states it isn't and come to an understanding."

This makes sense. I was hoping there would be an easier way to identify which trait(s) lead to lifetime computations—do I have to wait for tooling to be built into RLS eventually (e.g. I know there is a similar functionality for identifying the computed type of an AST node in IntelliJ), or are there tools that might assist with this already?